# Where can I find a REST API of stars and constellations?

Tags: api, astronomy

I'm looking for an open REST API to make ocasional queries of stars and constellations. Concretly I'm looking for getting the right ascension and declination of the most important stars of a few constellations (other parameters are optional).

Comment: Have you come across http://star-api.herokuapp.com/ which is open source at https://github.com/HacktheUniverse/star-api ? The data appears to be from http://www.amnh.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For simple, there is a webservice called [LookUP](http://www.strudel.org.uk/lookUP/about.html) which provides a web, REST and XML api for star and constellation data by name.

If that doesn't quite meet your need, there's [SIMBAD Astronomical Database](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/), which is where the above-noted LookUP tool is getting its data.

Comment: I've found SIMBAD yesterday and is perfect for my needs. Thank you